# AFNetworking:Asynchronous image download using setImageWithURLRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I have a image slider and am downloading images from url using setImageWithURLRequest. Suppose a user slide from left to right as soon as app code then I have to show the rightmost index image which I can achieve but after that I have to download images from beginning of the index. How to achieve that?

```
for (int i = 0; i < self.items.count; i++) {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = scrollView.frame.size;
    UIView *subview = self.view;

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    subview = imageView;

    NSURLRequest *imagerequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[_items objectAtIndex:i]];
    __weak UIImageView *weakImageView = (UIImageView *) subview;

    [(UIImageView *) subview setImageWithURLRequest:imagerequest
                                placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.gif"]
                                         success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

                                             UIImageView *strongImageView = weakImageView; // make local strong reference to protect against race conditions
                                             if (!strongImageView) return;

                                             strongImageView.image = image;

                                         }
                                         failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                             //[activityIndicatorView removeFromSuperview];

                                             // do any other error handling you want here
                                         }];

    [scrollView addSubview:subview];
}
```

Comment: Add some of your code please

Answer (score 1):

U can use `UIImageView+AFNetworking.h`:

```
- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url
       placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage;
```

Example:

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:<url> placeholderImage:<image>];
```

Or:

```
- (void)setImageWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest
              placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage
                       success:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image))success
                       failure:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error))failure;
```

Example:

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:<url> placeholderImage:<image> success:<successBlock> failure:<faliureBlock>];
```

Comment: I am using setImageWithURLRequest method for asynchronous image download. But what i need to do is when user slide left to right then the index where it stopped i have to load that image which is happening using setImageWithURLRequest method but then at the same time all other images should also get download one by one.